# Encoding.Default not working in Unity Player

Tags: c#, php, encoding, unity-game-engine, base64

I recently went thru a small issue with my app, which basically downloads a string and an image from my website, now it works perfectly in the Unity Editor, but when I build and run, it doesn't print the image properly anymore! Here is the important code

```
byte[] data = sendMessage("https://mywebsite.com", values);
string ret = Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
var split = ret.Split(new string[] {"//"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
byte[] texdata = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(split[1]);
varstr = split[0];
```

texdata is used in the tex.LoadImage(); and varstr is saved for later, now it all works fine and dandy when I'm in the editor but when built, the image shows a big ? (the png is invalid) and varstr doesn't return properly. I am 100% sure it's the encoding, as when just doing

```
byte[] data = sendMessage("https://mywebsite.com", values);
byte[] texdata = data;
```

Where sendMessage() only returns the image and not the string, it works perfectly in build and in editor, moreso, I've tried string ret = Convert.ToBase64String(data); but then ret.Split(); returns

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.

So yeah, that's pretty much it, and I hope you have a nice day!

- P.S: My website is php and sendMessage() works perfectly

Comment: I think you'd benefit from using a debugger and looking at the actual data to see what's different in the editor vs. runtime. Failing that, print statements should be good enough to debug this. Some specific things: it doesn't make sense for `Split` to throw `IndexOutOfRangeException`, did you mean `split[1]`? Also, is the data base64? It doesn't make sense to use `ToBase64String` unless it really is. You probably just don't have base64 data, which explains why there aren't any `/` characters when you try to convert!

Comment: Yes, my bad I meant split[1]

Answer (score 1):

If it is an encoding issue within that code, look at [`Encoding.Default.EncodingName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.encodingname(v=vs.110).aspx) in the editor vs. during runtime. This will tell you if the default encodings are different.

As a potential solution, don't use the default. For example, use [`Encoding.UTF8`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8(v=vs.110).aspx). If you find out which encoding the Unity editor is using, you can use that.

Comment: It returns 1252, and I did try 1252, 1252 returns a blank image when i try feeding it to tex.LoadImage() on runtime, a blank image not an error image but a blank one, for some reasons, @31eee384, also, I tried encoding the php data to utf-8, but then many characters miss and the image (png) is not valid anymore, in a nutcase, what encoding should i use to encode my image?

Answer (score 0):

I did fix it by finding the encoding of the data my website sent me using `echo mb_internal_encoding();`  which is ISO-8859-1, and then I created `Encoding ISO = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");` and used that instead of Default and it worked just like i wanted it to!