# Unity Serialize and Encoding sprite

Tags: unity-game-engine, serialization, encoding, sprite

I'm trying to download and save file, on android device. It's works fine on PC, but i have a visual bug at my android phone. Look at screen please

[image]

My code:
It's how i download and serialize it

```c#
Icon = Sprite.Create(texture2dd, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, texture2dd.width, texture2dd.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100.0f);

byte[] texturebytes = Icon.texture.GetRawTextureData();
File.WriteAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/icon", Encoding.Default.GetString(texturebytes));
File.WriteAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/iconinfo", Icon.texture.width + "@@@" + Icon.texture.height);
```

And thi is how I try to load it later:

```c#
string[] info = File.ReadAllText(path + "info").Split(new string[] { "@@@" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
int width, height;
int.TryParse(info[0], out width);
int.TryParse(info[1], out height);
byte[] bytesIcon = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(File.ReadAllText(path));
Texture2D iconText = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
iconText.LoadRawTextureData(bytesIcon);
iconText.Apply();
return Sprite.Create(iconText, new Rect(0, 0, width, height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
```

I think problem in Encoding type, but i tryed all Encoding types, and it's still don't work, and load some bug-texture.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `GetRawTextureData()` and `LoadRawTextureData` you should save it actually as a `.png` or `.jpg` format! The "RawTextureData" is very huge compared to the pure `.jpg` or `.png` file data.

---

Instead use [`EncodeToPNG`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.EncodeToPNG.html) (or `EncodeToJPG` if the quality is not that important - than remember to also adopt the file ending) and [`LoadImage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.LoadImage.html).

Additionally `LoadImage` actually "knows" the image size (because it is encoded into the `png` or `jpg` file) so there is no need for your `iconinfo` file at all!

Something like

```c#
// ...
Icon = Sprite.Create(texture2dd, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, texture2dd.width, texture2dd.height), Vector2.one * 0.5f, 100.0f);

byte[] texturebytes = Icon.texture.EncodeToPNG();
File.WriteAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/icon.png", Encoding.Default.GetString(texturebytes));
// ...
```

(Maybe also checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54558284/7111561) for other ways to write the file.)

and

```c#
// ...
byte[] bytesIcon = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(File.ReadAllText(path));
// as the example in the documentation states:
//   Texture size does not matter, since
//   LoadImage will replace it with incoming image size.
Texture2D iconText = new Texture2D(2, 2);
iconText.LoadImage(bytesIcon);
// Also from the documentation:
//   Texture will be uploaded to the GPU automatically; there's no need to call Apply.
return Sprite.Create(iconText, new Rect(0, 0, iconText.width, iconText.height), Vector2.one * 0.5f);
```

And yes another issue might still be that you used `Encoding.Default` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31256623/encoding-default-not-working-in-unity-player)) so maybe you should also use a fixed encoding like `Encoding.UTF8`.

---

Though for loading the file I would actually prefere to use a [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-RetrievingTexture.html) which can be also used for a file from the local filestorage!

Comment: Thank you for response. I'm tryed it, but it's don't load image. Just white square(

Comment: did you try the `FileStream` solution instead for loading? I'm not sure if maybe `ReadAllText` causes some issues